# Spin Dynamics in strong magnetic Field

Tags: spin-statistics

it is well known, that the spin of spinning particles such as electrons is aligned when placed in a strong magnetic field. In other words one says that the propability of measuring the electrons spin in positive z-direction is close to unity, when the electron before was placed in a strong magnetic field directing in negative z-direction because this is the energetically cheaper configuration of the electron.

But what are the quantum mechanical dynamics behind this spin alignement process? Because if I just use as the Hamiltonian

\begin{align}
\hat{H}=-\mu_B \cdot \hat{\sigma}_zB_z^{\mathrm{strong}},
\end{align}
the only thing I get is the ordinary spin precession. Do I have to incoorporate some other interaction processes or something like this? I know there are some spin statistical models, which would describe spin flips but shouldn't it be possible to formulate the dynamics of this process also for a single spin?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What does it mean for the magnetic field to be strong...

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments. Yes meanwhile I think too, that I need to add processes where the magnetic energy gain could "flow", like photon emission. I know from the field of MRI, that photons could be absorbed or emitted (by a nuclear spin flip) in the radio frequency range, when a magnet field of a few teslar is provided.